# отправка POSIX сигналов через SSH

Tags: linux, c, signal

На удаленном компе с MIPS архитектурой и операционкой 2.4.36-btvt GNU/Linux запущена программа DogRequest, которая ждет сигнала SIGUSR1, после чего должна выполнить некоторые действия. Обработчик сигналов данной программы выглядит следующим образом:

```
static void handle_signal(int signal)
{
  switch(signal)
  {
    case SIGUSR1:
        Requested = 1; //Flag
        break;
    default:
        break;
   }
}
```

Инициализация sigaction:

```
  struct sigaction sa;
  // Setup the sighub handler
  sa.sa_handler = &handle_signal;

  // Restart the system call, if at all possible
  sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;

   if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot handle SIGUSR1"); // Should not happen
   }
```

Через ssh соединение, со своего компа с архитектурой x86_64 отправляю команду:

```
kill -10 PID
```

Но вместо того чтобы принять и обработать этот сигнал, программа на удаленном компе завершается. С помощью вывода в файл я установил, что при поступлении сигнала обработчик сигналов даже не вызывается, хотя системный вызов sigaction был запущен.

При этом если я запускаю программу DogRequest у себя на компе и посылаю SIGUSR1 запущенной программе, то сигнал нормально обрабатывается и все нужные мне действия выполняются. Что может являться причиной того, что отправленный мною сигнал через ssh не обрабатывается и программа завершается?

Answer (score 1):

Все просто, в архитектурах MIPS и x86 коды сигналов различаются. Пользовательский сигнал SIGUSR1 для архитектуры x86 имеет код 10, а для архитектуры MIPS 16. Поэтому если Вы подключаетесь с хоста под архитектурой x86 к хосту с архитектурой MIPS через SSH и пытаетесть отправить работающей там программе сигнал SIGUSR1, то Вам необходимо указать код сигнала соответствующий архитектуре компьютера, на которой работает программа, то есть -16.

Comment: А еще `kill` поддерживает имена сигналов `kill -s SIGUSR1 PID`

Comment: А ещё он поддерживает их в более краткой форме: `kill -USR1 pid`